# I am created combobox in datagridview and it retrive the data through database, I want when I run the page combobox shows the default value

Tags: c#

I am working on windows application,combo box works perfectly but by default when I run the page ,it shows blank , I want to show the default value.I am using this code.

```
public void combofill()
{
    cmb.Items.Clear();
    cmb.Items.Add("select");
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(con1);
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select Name from mr000 where Type&0x0f=3", con);
    SqlDataReader dr;
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Load(dr);
    cmb.DataSource = dt;
    cmb.Name = "combocust";
    cmb.DisplayMember = "Name";
    cmb.HeaderText = "Change Customer";
    dataGridView1.Columns.Insert(3, cmb);
    con.Close();
}
```

Comment: So just set the value to whatever you want... `cmb.Text = "Some default name from the list";`

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
 public void FillCmbo(String Sql, ComboBox cmb, String name)
   {
       try
       {
           if (Con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
               Con.Close();
           Con.Open();

          SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Sql, Con);
           SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select Name from mr000 where Type&0x0f=3", con);
           DataTable dt = new DataTable();
           con.Fill(dr);        
           dt.Rows.InsertAt(Drw, 0);
           cmb.Name = "combocust";
           cmb.DisplayMember =name;
           cmb.HeaderText = "Change Customer";
           cmb.DataSource = dt;
       }
       catch (System.Exception ex)
       {

           MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Check", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
       }
   }
```

you can also use

```
ComboBox.selectIndex=0;
```